# reducing an n-order differential equation to a first order system of equations using either sagemath or sympy

Tags: math, numerical-methods, sympy, ode, sage

I want to reduce a n-order ordinary differential equation into a first order system of equations. This is in preparation for numerical analysis. I use both Sympy and Sagemath for Computer Algebra, but I have not found any functions in them to do this type of reduction. I was not sure if anyone else could indicate whether this functionality exists within either Sympy or Sagemath.

An example of this would be reducing the equation:

```
x''' - 2x'' + x' = 0
```

to a system of first order equations:

```
[0  1 0 
 0  0 1 
 0 -1 2]
```

Comment: try search for Laplace or Z transformations which are commonly used for this purpose

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for the note. I am not sure if the Laplace transform is the right idea here. So I want to take say a second or third order differential equation and convert it to a first order system. I actually want to use a computer algebra tool like Sympy or Sage so that I can check my own algebra for mistakes. Using the Laplace transform would work as a method to solve the equation, but I am not sure it would convert a third order homogeneous differential equation into a first order system of differential equations. Perhaps you could explain what you mean.

Comment: added answer (it is a comment really but in comments it would be unreadable)

Comment: @Spektre the OP is looking to convert an ODE into a system of first order ODEs that can be solved numerically e.g. using eigenvalue methods. See [here](http://www.math.poly.edu/courses/ma2132/Notes/MA2132EquationsToSystems.pdf) for some examples.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, SymPy doesn't have a function that does this directly, but it's straightforward to do manually.

I'm assuming you always want your two additional equations to be of the form `y = x'` and `z = y'`.

First, let's create the ODE (in SymPy, expressions are automatically assumed to equal zero, so to simplify things, let's not bother with with `= 0` part). I'll assume your independent variable is `t`.

```
In [4]: t = symbols('t')

In [7]: x, y, z = symbols('x y z', cls=Function)

In [6]: ode = x(t).diff(t, t) - 2*x(t).diff(t) + x(t)

In [13]: ode = x(t).diff(t, 3) - 2*x(t).diff(t, t) + x(t).diff(t)

In [14]: ode
Out[14]:
               2           3
d             d           d
──(x(t)) - 2⋅───(x(t)) + ───(x(t))
dt             2           3
             dt          dt
```

Now if we replace `x'` with `y`,

```
In [15]: ode.subs(x(t).diff(t), y(t))
Out[15]:
                      2
         d           d
y(t) - 2⋅──(y(t)) + ───(y(t))
         dt           2
                    dt
```

we see that it also replaces `x''` with `y'`. So let's substitute `y'` with `z`:

```
In [16]: ode = ode.subs(x(t).diff(t), y(t)).subs(y(t).diff(t), z(t))

In [17]: ode
Out[17]:
                d
y(t) - 2⋅z(t) + ──(z(t))
                dt
```

Now our system `[x' y' z']` is

```
In [20]: Matrix([y(t), z(t), solve(ode, z(t).diff(t))[0]])
Out[20]:
⎡     y(t)     ⎤
⎢              ⎥
⎢     z(t)     ⎥
⎢              ⎥
⎣-y(t) + 2⋅z(t)⎦
```

Note that we already know that `x' = y` and `y' = z`, so we just use those directly, but we use `solve()` to get our substituted ODE in terms of `z'`.

If you want the coefficients, a simple trick is to take the Jacobian:

```
In [23]: M = Matrix([y(t), z(t), solve(ode, z(t).diff(t))[0]]).jacobian([x(t), y(t), z(t)])

In [24]: M
Out[24]:
⎡0  1   0⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎢0  0   1⎥
⎢        ⎥
⎣0  -1  2⎦
```

I'll leave the task of wrapping this up into a single function `ode_to_system(ode, [x(t), y(t), z(t)])` as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 4):

I have written an experimental library to deal with systems of ordinary differential equations:

https://github.com/bjodah/symodesys

it is based on sympy, unfortunately I haven't written much documentation but I provide quite a few examples. I would tackle your equation as follows:

```
from sympy import *
from symodesys.odesys import AnyOrderODESystem

t = Symbol('t')
x = Function('x')(t)

D1x = x.diff(t)
D2x = x.diff(t, 2)
D3x = x.diff(t, 3)

expr = Eq(D3x, 2*D2x - D1x)

odesys = AnyOrderODESystem.from_list_of_eqs([expr])
print(odesys.all_depv)
redsys = odesys.reduce_to_sys_of_first_order()
print(redsys.all_depv)
print(redsys.f)
```

Which outputs:

```
[x(t)]
[x(t), x_h1(t), x_h2(t)]
OrderedDict([(x(t), x_h1(t)), (x_h1(t), x_h2(t)), (x_h2(t), -x_h1(t) + 2*x_h2(t))])
```

adding a few extra lines gives you a gui to experiment with an initial value problem
(see solution curves as function of initial values)

```
from symodesys.gui import get_chaco_viewer
from collections import defaultdict
y0 = defaultdict(int)
y0[redsys['x']] = 3.14
params = {}
t0, tend, N = 0, 10, 100
viewer = get_chaco_viewer(redsys, y0, params, t0, tend, N)
viewer.configure_traits()
viewer.clean_up()
```

which gives you:

[image: symodesys gui]

it's a little tricky to install some of the dependencies, add a comment if you need help!

Answer (score 3):

The question is, how would you encode the differential equation as a string in the first place. Because encoding is already more complex than writing down the first order system.

The general manual procedure is to set x1=x, x2=x', x3=x'' and then to notice that

```
x1'=x'=x2
x2'=x''=x3
x3'=x'''= 2*x'' - x' = 2*x3 - x2
```

and then transform the resulting system into matrix form.

See also companion matrix for polynomials, this is (up to transposition) also the general form that you obtain for a system matrix for a linear differential equation of higher order.

Comment: No need to encode strings. That's the whole point of using SymPy or Sage, which can represent symbolic objects directly.

Comment: You need to encode the ODE as some code object, as input, in a form that can be parsed and interpreted by the CAS. I:e., transfer the equation from paper to computer. Even if it is trivial, depending on the method, the effort will be comparable to manually establishing the first order system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Sympy or Sagemath. but look for Laplace or Z transform inside their API documentations.

- if found then you have less work to do
- if not you will have to find lib or code it yourself

solve differential system by use of Laplace

- **I did not use this for quite a while so check all with some math books!!!**
- anyway if I remember it right
- Laplace transform convert integral function to linear function (time domain to s domain)
- your differential functions just have to have continuous derivations/integrals to make this work
- to solve your problem do this:

  1. convert all differentials to integral by integrating the whole thing
  2. apply Laplace transform

     - this will convert differential system to polynomial system
     - [wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform_applied_to_differential_equations)
  3. solve the polynomial system of equations
  4. apply inverse Laplace transform

     - this will convert the partial results to your solution's result
  5. solve the integration constants by edge cases defined by your probem
- also look [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx) for another examples
- there are tons of stuff about this topic just google

solve differential system by Z

- never done that but should be similar if not the same as solution by Laplace transform